# Reuse MariaDB-data-folder when installing MariaDB again?

Tags: mariadb

I've got MariaDB 10.4.1 installed. Run it now for a while. Had troubles to upgrade to 11.4 on Windows 10 and ended with not having a running version of MariaDB any more.

What is left, is the data-part of MariaDB. For my vital data, I hava a backup. But for some test databases, I don't. So it is not really critically, but I wonder, how I could reuse the data from the old installation with the new one.

I tried, by just replacing the data-path of a new installation with this saved one. This gave me an access-problem when starting mariadb with cmd "mariadbd.exe --console". I fixed this. Now, I get the messages and have no clue how to proceed.

```
> 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [Note] mariadbd.exe (mysqld 10.4.11-MariaDB)
> starting as process 5964 ... InnoDB: using atomic writes. 2023-12-31
> 11:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked
> functions 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
> 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
> 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1 2023-12-31
> 11:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions 2023-12-31
> 11:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M,
> instances = 1, chunk size = 128M 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [Note] InnoDB:
> Completed initialization of buffer pool 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: Resetting space id's in the doublewrite buffer 2023-12-31
> 11:51:01 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to open undo tablespace
> '.\\undo1061'. 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin
> initialization aborted with error Generic error 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0
> [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown... 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [ERROR]
> Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error. 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0
> [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
> 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled. 2023-12-31
> 11:51:01 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
> 2023-12-31 11:51:01 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Any idea about this? Or a suggestion, how to get it run with another approach?

I wasn't aware of this consistent data-folder before. I would like to backup this folder. It fits to my automatic tools for backing up - rather than issue a database-dump - command every now an then.

Comment: [downgrade documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/downgrading-between-major-versions-of-mariadb/).

Comment: The word **must** is mentioned two times in the [doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/downgrading-between-major-versions-of-mariadb/)  danblack is [referring](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334445/reuse-mariadb-data-folder-when-installing-mariadb-again#comment651097_334445) to, that's why I commented in [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77738918/reuse-mariadb-data-folder-when-installing-mariadb-again#comment137050256_77738918) that a backup is soo much easier (There are too much wanna-be dba people, who think having a correct backup is not valid for them on SO)

Comment: Is there a file named "undo1061" in the data directory? If not, it is not an access problem, but something else.